# Can I hide some applications from menu, but leave it searchable?

Tags: release-hera, slingshot, menu

I want hide some applications from menu, but leave it searchable from search field in app menu.
This beheavior is similar to Onboard application. Which icon not visible on menu, but may be find with search field.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by editing the corresponding *.desktop files, or the easiest way is to use an app called AppEditor, you can find it in appCenter. Just uncheck 'show in launcher' and save.